# Perl: how to supply regexp list from file

Tags: regex, perl

So, I need parse a file and if something matches the pattern, replace it with something:

```
while(<$ifh>) {
  s/(.*pattern_1*)/$1\nsome more stuff/ ;
  s/(.*pattern_2*)/$1\neven more stuff/;
  s/(.*pattern_3.*)// ;
  # and so on ...
  print $ofh $_;
}
```

Question: what would be a simplest way to have this regexp rules list in the file (something similar to  sed '-f' option)?

EDIT: perhaps I need to clarify a bit. We need to have the regexp rules in the separate file (not in the parsed file - although this was nice, thanks!), so they are not hardcoded. So, basically the external file should consist of 's//' lines.
Of course this can probably be done with foreach loop and eval, or even with external call to sed, but I suppose there can be something nicer.

regards, Wojtek

Comment: Perhaps you should explain why you do not want to have the regexes in your program file. I assume that despite saying you want the regexes in "the file", that you actually meant that you want a third file for them, so that you have program file, input file and regex file.

Answer (score 0):

You could create patterns and store them in a Perl list, then simply iterate through your patterns in your input loop.

```
my @patterns = ( qr/pattern1/, qr/pattern2/, qr/pattern3/, etc..);
while(<$ifh>) {
   for my $pattern (@patterns) {
      s/($pattern)/$1\neven more stuff/;
   }
   print $ofh $_;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your edit, here's a way to store regular expressions in an external file.  Note that I would not recommend storing whole `s/.../.../` statements in an external file, but you could use the `eval` function to accomplish it.  Here's how I would solve this, however:

```
my (@regexes,$i);
$i=0;
while (my $line=<$rifh>) {
  chomp($line);
  if (index($line, "::")>-1) {
    my @texts=split(/::/,$line);
    $regexes[$i]{"to find"} = qr!$texts[0]!;
    $regexes[$i]{"replace with"} = $texts[1];
    $i++;
  }
}

while (my $line=<$ifh>) {
  chomp($line);
  foreach my $regex (@regexes)
     $line ~= s!$regex->{"to find"}!$regex->{"replace with"}!;
  print $ofh $line . "\n";
}
```

(My use of `!` as a regexp delimiter is my own style mechanism, often useful for allowing bare `/` characters to be used directly in a regexp definition.)

Comment: That is more or less something I expected. Thanks a lot!