# Alternative to many substitutions in a row?

Tags: regex, perl

Most of my Perl scripts deal with converting ugly formats to the plain TXT content. So far, I've done this with dozens and dozens of substitutions all in a row. Is there a more elegant way to do this in Perl? For instance, a hash containing all the s/// pairs, or even an external file containing the substitutions?

I'm just wondering how other people handle this kind of formatting script, or if just having a novel's worth of s/// expressions is the normal way to go. It gets hard to manage at a certain point.

Thanks!

Comment: This is hard to answer without a specific example. If you're talking about doing `s/a/A/`, `s/b/B/`, `s/c/C/`, etc. then I would use `tr///`; with slightly more complex regexes, I might combine them into a single regex, either "manually" or with `join '|', @patterns` or something like that; in other cases, I would do something else.

Comment: I think the [second answer in this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19658769/perl-how-to-supply-regexp-list-from-file) is what you are looking for..

Comment: Thanks, ThisSuitIsBlackNot. My applications are a little specialized but I will try to give a specific example. One instance is a long RTF file with code for a TV teleprompter such as "SOV----------" and other ugly commands that I individually get rid of, leaving only the actual text content. So that's why I can't just condense several s/// into one.

Comment: I've never tried it, but maybe [`Regex::Assemble`](http://search.cpan.org/~rsavage/Regexp-Assemble-0.36/lib/Regexp/Assemble.pm) would be useful.

Comment: Since 5.10, Regex::Assemble is redundant with `join '|'`

Comment: You speak about a dozen and dozen of replacements, sometimes formats seem ugly because man takes not the time to see their structure with more precision. It's the most important step of the job.

Comment: This question isn't so bad to deserve the downvote and the close votes (IMHO), but it would benefit from some specific examples of what the OP is trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes the most efficient approach is to parse the old data format into a memory structure and then output the new format.

Depending on the structure, this can be done line by line. But if you have to do the whole document that works, as long as they aren't too gigantic.

As an example, this is how you'd do an image file conversion: read a GIF into a bitmap and then produce a JPEG output. You wouldn't use regular expressions, even if you *could*, it would be horribly inefficient.

Comment: I don't think that helps a lot without an example. I realise that the OP has offered no sample data, but it would have been best to ask for something before writing a very generic solution

Answer (score 1):

I have a utility method I use all the time for this:

```
sub subst($@) {
    my($x, @map) = @_;
    @map % 2 == 0 or die 'subst requires an odd number of params';
    while (@map) {
        my $from = shift(@map);
        my $to = shift(@map);
        $x =~ s/$from/$to/g;
    }
    return $x;
}
```

I use a list instead of a hash for `map` so I can control the order. Use it like this:

```
my $new_x = subst($x,
    pattern1 => replacement1,
    pattern2 => replacement2);
```

Even with a single pattern, it's simpler if you aren't substituting something in place. I.e. it's cleaner than this:

```
my $new_x = $x;
$new_x =~ s/pattern1/replacement1/g;
```

Answer (score 0):

Zan Lynx gives good advice, but to answer your question about hash-driven substitutions, you can use the following:

```
my %replacements = (
   foo => 'bar',
   bar => 'baz',
   baz => 'foo',
   # ...
);

my $pat = join '|', map quotemeta, keys %replacements;

s/($pat)/$replacements{$1}/g;
```

This solves two problems:

- It scans the input only once, not once per pattern.
- It takes away the risk of accidentally matching the replacements of earlier substitutions. In fact, the example I used couldn't be accomplished with three substitutions.

Answer (score -2):

This is an awkward question because the *order* of the substitutions affects the result

If your changes are so extensive then I would much prefer a sequence of `s///` statements to anything held in a hash, which would shuffle the substitutions into a different order each time the program was run

I would still be worried about the accuracy of *“dozens and dozens”* (two hundred plus?) of substitutions, but at least the result would be under control